# Reload Package List -> Downloading Translation... failed

Tags: package-management, apt, synaptic

When using Synaptic with Ubuntu 11.04, it always tries to download *lots* of translation repositories, but the calls fail. This hasn't happened for me with earlier versions of Ubuntu. It's pretty annoying, because this often causes the package list reloading to take quite some time.

When reloading the packages with aptitude, the situation is similar: There, it doesn't "fail", but it prints `[IGNORED]` for each of them.

There's no special "Translations" entry in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Screenshot:

[image]

My /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
```

Comment: I guess this simply means your package list is up-to-date, and there is no need to download it again. Apt uses some magic checksums to determine whether there is need to download the package list, and otherwise it ignores it. This is likely, for the translations are rarely updated.

Comment: @rafalcieslak: Ok interesting, could be the case. But the lookup process often takes very long, and I don't actually need or want any translations.

Comment: Sometimes it may take some time, depending on your internet connection. But it is anyway shorter than as if it was actually downloading the translation package lists. Did you try using another mirror?

Comment: @chris-lercher : Can you please put answer your question and mark it as answered. It is as per the [AskUbuntu community policies](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1282/is-it-possible-to-ask-a-question-you-already-know-and-answer-it)

Comment: @Manish: I would, if I had an answer... (rafalcieslak posted a comment, but as he says, this is only a guess. This is perfectly fine for a comment, but not something I will accept as an answer.)

Comment: I think you are correct. If I remember correctly, I get `Ign` instead of `Failed` when there is nothing to download

Comment: Can you also try changing the mirror. Is the mirror up and working?

Comment: @Manish: Ok, I just tried a server from Italy, the US server, and the main server. Although they're all somewhat faster than the German server I have used so far, they always show "Failed" for the translation files. Do you think there is an option to completely disable downloading translations?

Comment: Can you update your question with your computer's `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

Comment: @Manish: Ok, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is normal, as it happened to me every time I update the package lists. And I've used Ubuntu since 2007. Probably it just means nothing has changed and that it does not have to download a new list.

Comment: Ok, I actually haven't seen this with older versions of Ubuntu (I'm also a long time user, though I admit that I made a little "pause" in 2009/2010).